# Computing Möbius function of the natural numbers set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, order-theory, mobius-inversion

Let $N$ be the set of all natural numbers. Consider the poset $(N,\leq)$ where $\forall$ $r,s$ in $N$, $r\leq s$ iff $s$=$r^n$ for some $n$ in $N$. Compute the Möbius function of that poset. I have been trying to compute it, but I got nowhere. I think The Hall's Theorem may help
[How to calculate the mobius function of a Poset using Hall's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188274/how-to-calculate-the-mobius-function-of-a-poset-using-halls-theorem?fbclid=IwAR2BChofmSpUpjcsYR4vYvrzT4VAonDAroyDyOEwiK34pe1RwjBHDmx621U)
, but I have difficulty to compute the number of m-chains between $r$ and $s$. Is Hall's theorem the right way to do this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of a chain from $r$ to $s=r^n$ must be powers of $r$ with each exponent dividing the next one. Thus these chains are in bijective correspondence with the chains between $1$ and $n$ in the divisibility poset. Thus
$$
\mu_{(\mathbb N,\le)}(r,r^n)=\mu_{(\mathbb N,\,\mid\,)}(1,n)=\mu(n)=\begin{cases}
+1&\text{$n$ is squarefree with an even number of prime factors,}\\
-1&\text{$n$ is squarefree with an odd number of prime factors,}\\
0&\text{$n$ is not squarefree.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Looove it! Thank you!